# Getting the ultrametric distance from clusterfck library

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am using this library: 
http://harthur.github.io/clusterfck/

I get the following extract from hierarchical clustering:

```
[
  {"canonical":[20,120,102],
   "size":1
  },
  {"canonical":[250,255,253],
   "left":{
      "canonical":[250,255,253],
      "size":1
    },
   "right":{
      "canonical":[255,255,240],
      "size":1
    },
   "size":2
  },
  {"canonical":[100,54,300],
   "size":1
  }
]
```

As you can see it does not state the ultrametric distance. Is there a way of getting the *ultrametric distance* data from the clustering? Or if there are any other libraries which can supply that value?

Comment: Use the source of clusterfck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/harthur/clusterfck/pull/8

Has a pull request on the library, but the author seems to not care implementing it.